# Is line-joining unsupported by f-strings?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-3.6, f-string

Is the following syntax not supported by f-strings in Python 3.6?  If I line join my f-string, the substitution does not occur:

```
SUB_MSG = "This is the original message."

MAIN_MSG = f"This longer message is intended to contain " \
             "the sub-message here: {SUB_MSG}"

print(MAIN_MSG)
```

returns:

```
This longer message is intended to contain the sub-message here: {SUB_MSG}
```

If I remove the line-join:

```
SUB_MSG = "This is the original message."

MAIN_MSG = f"This longer message is intended to contain the sub-message here: {SUB_MSG}"

print(MAIN_MSG)
```

it works as expected:

```
This longer message is intended to contain the sub-message here: This is the original message.
```

In [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#id27), backslashes **within** an f-string are expressly not supported:

> Escape sequences
>
> Backslashes may not appear inside the expression portions of
>   f-strings, so you cannot use them, for example, to escape quotes
>   inside f-strings:
>
> ```
> >>> f'{\'quoted string\'}'
> ```

Are line-joins considered 'inside the expression portion of f-strings' and are thus not supported?

Comment: Not supported within the *expression portions of f-strings*, not elsewhere. Also, just add `f` to the second string literal. This is consistent with how other string prefixes work: `len(r"\\" "\\") == 3`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to mark both strings as `f`-strings to make it work, otherwise the second one is interpreted as normal string:

```
SUB_MSG = "This is the original message."

MAIN_MSG = f"test " \
           f"{SUB_MSG}"

print(MAIN_MSG)
```

Well, in this case you could also just make the second string the f-string because the first one doesn't contain anything to interpolate:

```
MAIN_MSG = "test " \
           f"{SUB_MSG}"
```

Note that this affects all string-prefixes not just f-strings:

```
a = r"\n" \
     "\n"
a   # '\\n\n'   <- only the first one was interpreted as raw string

a = b"\n" \
     "\n"   
# SyntaxError: cannot mix bytes and nonbytes literals
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this (note the extra “f” on the continuation line):

```
SUB_MSG = "This is the original message."

# f strings must be aligned to comply with PEP and pass linting
MAIN_MSG = f"This longer message is intended to contain " \
           f"the sub-message here: {SUB_MSG}"


print(MAIN_MSG)
```